# Is it possible to support JS by Portia by using splash?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, splash-screen, portia, scrapinghub

Is it possible to support js by portia using splash download middlware middlware in slybot?

I am trying to connect splash via docker with portia. how to import the download splash middleware in to slybot path "C:\portia-master\portia-master\slybot\slybot" also let me know how to set the path in setting.py in this path